# Testing for even numbers in Java without modulo operator

Tags: java, syntax, logic, bit-manipulation

How would I do this in Java? Find if a number is divisible by 2, if the last digit is even. (0,2,4,6,8) Example: 128 is, 129 is not

Answer (score 16):

Use the bitwise operation `and`

```
if( (number&1) == 0)
```

**Bitwise AND operator &**

> The & (bitwise AND) operator compares each bit of its first operand to
>   the corresponding bit of the second operand. If both bits are 1's, the
>   corresponding bit of the result is set to 1. Otherwise, it sets the
>   corresponding result bit to 0 ([source](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/bitande.htm)).

In the **binary** format even numbers has the **Least significant bit equal to zero**. knowing this and using the & operator you can find out if it is even or not.

So it takes a number ..abcdy and compares with ..00001 if y is zero than ..abcdy & ..00001 is also zero, thus a even number.

Answer (score 6):

see if the the right most bit is 1 then its not, by using bitwise operators

perform logical and with (for example)

```
yourNumber & 1
```

Answer (score 6):

Check the least significant bit:

```
boolean even = (x & 1) == 0;
```

LSB is `0` for even number and `1` for odd, just like for decimal numbers least significant digit is `0` if it's dividable by `10`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if((n|1)==n)
  System.out.println("odd");
else
  System.out.println("even");
```

Reason: number is odd if the LSB is 1, and even otherwise. When n|1 is done, LSB of odd stays the same so the resulting number is not changed, while LSB of a even number becomes 1, thus changing the number.

Answer (score 0):

Myway ;)

public class Even_Odd {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int val=550;
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while(val>=0)
    {
        if(val==1)
        {
            System.out.println("Odd Number");
        }
        else if(val==0)
        {
            System.out.println("Even Number");
        }

            val=val-2;
        //  System.out.println(val);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thats cool.. But how many times the while loop executes if you have a 15-20 digit number. Perfomance sucks.. You should learn the better way of doing things though they are hard to learn at first. Not just you , but in general as a programme.r

Answer (score 0):

Divide the number by **2** and multiply the answer **2**, if you get your original number then the number is **"Even"** if not then the number is **"Odd"**

```
public class EvenOrOdd
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int value = 129;

        if((value/2)*2==value)
        {
            System.out.println("The Given Number \""+value+"\" is Even");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("The Given Number \""+value+"\" is Odd");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class CheckNumber{
public static void main(String... args)throws IOException{

    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.println("Please enter the number to check even or odd");

    int number=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    String temp=number+""; //convert number to string

    char ch=temp.charAt(temp.length()-1); //get last character

    temp=ch+"";

    if(temp.equals("0") || temp.equals("2") || temp.equals("4") || temp.equals("6") || temp.equals("8")) //check last number is even
        System.out.println("Number is even");
    else
        System.out.println("Number is odd");
}
```

}